# Git rejected non-fast forward

Tags: git, github

What I have locally are the correct stuff, meaning I just want to overwrite everything at group master, if there were changes make at group master by another member in my group. Does anyone know how I can do this? I'm getting the following error. (I simply want to push what I have to group master, ignoring all the changes made at group master by other members.)

It mentions "integrate remote changes", but I don't want to do that. I don't want any of the remote changes.

```
  $ git push group master

To git@github.com:name/groupNum.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:name/groupNum.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.




 $ git branch
  1
  some_name
  master
  random
* project2
```

When I did git push -f group master with a commit message, instead of pushing what I want to push (all of my changes) with my commit message, it just does the following, which reverts our repo to a commit a few months ago: "Revert "Revert "finished task 2 "" This reverts commit 86##6e9. " Why the "revert...", which is not even my commit message. How can I fix this now?

Comment: Did you want to push a branch other than master?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This message means that someone has published commits that share the common ancestor of the new commits on your branch.

If you know what these commits are and would like to completely overwrite them with yours, you can use the the `-f` flag to `git push`:

`git push -f group master`

Comment: How come, when I did that with a commit message, instead of pushing what I want to push with my commit message, it just does the following, which reverts our repo to a commit a few months ago: "Revert "Revert "finished task 2 ""
This reverts commit 86##6e9.
"

Comment: Make sure that when you run `push` you are on the branch that you are intending to push to master. Based on the output of your `git branch` it looks like you're trying to push project2.

Comment: Which branch should I be on when I do git push, then? Kinda confused.

Comment: in other words, how do I know which branch all of my changes that I want to push right now are in?

Comment: Use `git log` to figure out what commits are on your current head. Use `git checkout` to move your current head around from branch to branch. You might want to check out the docs on `git push` for more clarity: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: When I do "git branch" it tells me that I'm on project2. When I do git log I see a commit message which is in fact the commit I want to push to group master.

Comment: When I try git push group master again, it just tells me that everything is up to date when it its not. It doesn't let me push my latest changes with the commit message I'm seeing when I do "git log". So am I on a wrong branch?

Comment: @Jobs: that means your current branch (`project2`, also known as `HEAD` because `HEAD` is *always* "your current branch"—it's how "your current branch" is defined; you change branches by changing your `HEAD`) is what you want to have replace the group `master`.  Without going into details, we can say that `git push --force group project2:master` will do that.  Note that force-pushing creates a problem for *everyone else* using the group repository, but apparently there's already a problem so this may be a better problem than the one you have now...

Comment: omg that fixed my problem! I've been stuck on this issue for 2 months! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to force the changes if you want to discard other changes made by other members.

I would recommend you to fetch all and make a zip of your code

Please read about it before you execute it

```
git push group master --force
```